# is there any free way to open an encrypted sqlite db in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

well, I have an encrypted `sqlite DB` and I want to open it in my app,
is there any simple way like you do it in .net by simply  providing the key in the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following link http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/10/tutorial-iphone-sqlite-encryption-with.html

Comment: I saw it before but I can't keep bass with it ,,I use xcode 4 and it looks that the tutorial use an earlier version!! I mean there is no building tab in the interface!!